# Why do blobs appear in a repository before committing?

Tags: git

So I came across the following passage in section 3.1 of Pro Git:

"Let’s assume that you have a directory containing three files, and you stage them all and commit. Staging the files computes a checksum for each one (the SHA-1 hash we mentioned in Getting Started), stores that version of the file in the Git repository (Git refers to them as blobs), and adds that checksum to the staging area"

My question is this: Why does git "store a version of the file in the Git repository" prior to me committing those files?

Comment: That's how the index/staging area works. It creates all the parts of the commit and then when you issue the commit command, it connects those objects to your history.

Comment: You might be interested in reading https://matthew-brett.github.io/curious-git/curious_journey.html

Comment: To clarify siride: So git doesn't actually "move" files anywhere when committing a blob, it simply connects them to your history by introducing a commit object that refers to your blobs through trees. If that's the case, the index and the repository would only appear separate, but actually rely on the same files, right?

Comment: @Jack: yes. In fact, if you delete commits, the blobs usually remain until they are garbage collected. They can be recovered from your repository. What you think of as the normal history is just objects reachable from tags and branch heads (which are just labels pointing to commit objects). Anything not reachable from that object graph is irrelevant, though it may still be present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: *Why* questions are always tricky.]

There's a very mechanical answer (which I see [siride mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515933/why-do-blobs-appear-in-a-repository-before-committing#comment77993239_45515933)): the internal structure of Git's *index*, that mysterious object that Git uses to build up the *next* commit, stores only blob hash IDs.  Therefore, in order to have a copy of the file *in* the index (so that it will be in the next commit), it must be in the repository as a blob object.

There's a performance answer: by storing hash IDs in the index, Git makes new commits very quickly.

There's a data-recovery answer (which is kind of weak): by storing the blob in the repository in advance, you can get it back for a while, via `git fsck --lost-found`, if you accidentally do something bad to it.  (The weaknesses here are, or include, that if the blob matches an existing blob in the repository, it does not show up in the lost-found search; and you lose the file's *name*, which is often important to understanding its content.)

There's a design-aesthetic answer: perhaps Linus thought that `git add file` copying the file into the repository early was prettier than having `git commit` do it later.

You can choose any of these answers, or make up your own!